# Python slicing notation: s vs s[:]

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, sequence

In Python, can someone explain the difference between the use of "s" and "s[:]"? Here, "s" is a sequence type?

Examples:

```
s = [1,2,3]
```

```
s[:] = [1,2,3]
```

```
for i in s:
  print(i)
```

```
for i in s[:]:
  print(i)
```

Are there any differences?

I was thinking maybe the last example means "copy of s" which would allow for modifying s inside loop? What else?

**Update based on answers**

Thanks everyone. This shows the difference in a very concise way.

```
>>> s = [1,2,3]; t = s; s[:] = [2,3,4]; print(t)
[2, 3, 4]

>>> s = [1,2,3]; t = s; s = [2,3,4]; print(t)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Yes `s[:]` is equivalent with `s.copy()` if s is `list`.

Comment: Try `t = s; s[:] = ...; print(t)` and compare to `s = ...`…

Comment: Slicing is used to get specific indexes, but since you are leaving both the start and end values empty, you get the entire list. This method is usually used for deep copying a list.

Comment: @alec no deep copy. It is shallow copy.

Comment: It's a deep copy (assuming 1D list), a shallow copy would just be a pointer to the same list.

Comment: @alec A *shallow copy* is a new list but with the same values in it. A "pointer to the same list" is… just the same list.

Comment: @alec no, that's not how those terms are used (in Python, at least). See https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html.

Comment: @alec see this https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/copy.html#copy.copy

Comment: It's a shallow copy, a = [set(), 1, 2, 3]
id(a)
1934672263816
id(a[:])
1934672263624
id(a[0])
1934671565992
id(a[:][0])
1934671565992

Comment: I see. But for a 1D list there is no difference

Comment: Even a 1D list can also have objects.

Comment: To TL;DR the duplicate: `s = [...]` assigns an entirely new list object to `s`. `s[:] = [...]` *mutates* an existing list object and overwrites all its contents. This makes a difference if other variables also point to that list object. `for i in s` iterates over the list; `for i in s[:]` iterates over a slice of the list, where the slice is the size of the entire list, in essence you iterate over a copy of the list. There's no real appreciable difference in those last two cases.